# Program compiled with VS2013 runs much slower than its equivalent in linux

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, visual-studio-2013, image-segmentation

I downloaded an open source c++ project which is written linux. I wanted to run in on windows and installed MinGW in order to compile and run it. I have successfully compiled it with "make" command and program runs pretty fast. Later, I moved program to Visual Studio, modified few lines including deleting "sys/time.h" library etc.. but never made a big change in algorithm itself. When I run the code, it runs but much slower than it runs with its compiled version in MinGW.

I haven't change anything in the algoritm. What should be the reason and how can I make it faster again?

Project I mentioned is here: http://perso.esiee.fr/~coupriec/temporal_segm.zip

It basically segments a given image sequence and produces segments with colored randomly.

Comment: Did you compile in release or debug mode? VS is very slow in debug mode due to many checks that it performs to catch various errors.

Comment: Also, make sure you compile for the same architecture. VS will compile to 32-bit by default iirc.